# Dagger2 Named(@Named) Injection with polymorphism or different object

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dagger-2

Hi i am trying to study named injection in Dagger2

Here are my Java classes but none of them seems to be working.
What i want is that based on @Named annotation i wish to get different objects.

```
public interface Server {

    public void start();

    public void stop();

    public String request(String request);
}

public abstract class AbstractServer implements Server {

    private boolean started;

    @Override
    public void start() {
        started = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        if (!started) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Server was not started");
        }
    }
}

public class AudioServer extends AbstractServer{

     @Override
    public String request(String request) {
        return "Response from Audio server: " + request;
    }

}

public class VideoServer extends AbstractServer {

    @Override
    public String request(String request) {
        return "Response from Video server: " + request;
    }
}

@Module
public class ServerModule {

    public ServerModule() {
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("audio")
    @Singleton
    AudioServer provideAudioServer() {
        return new AudioServer();
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("video")
    @Singleton
    VideoServer provideVideoServer() {
        return new VideoServer();
    }
}
```

Please not ServerComponent.java is not compiling

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {ServerModule.class})
public interface ServerComponent {

    AudioServer provideAudioServer();

    VideoServer provideVideoServer();

    void inject(TestInject inject);

}

public class TestInject {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestInject.class.getSimpleName());

    @Inject
    @Named("audio")
    Server audioServer;

    public TestInject() {
//        ServerComponent component = DaggerServerComponent.builder()
//                .build();
//        component.inject(this);
    }

    public void test() {
        String serverResponse = null;
        if (audioServer != null) {
            serverResponse = audioServer.request("game.mp3");
            logger.warning(serverResponse);
        } else {
            serverResponse = "Failure";
            logger.info(serverResponse);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestInject inject = new TestInject();
        inject.test();
    }
}
```

---

**EDITED** Please see answer in `TestInject.java` and `ServerComponent.java`

```
public interface Server {

    public void start();

    public void stop();

    public String request(String request);
}

public abstract class AbstractServer implements Server {

    private boolean started;

    @Override
    public void start() {
        started = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        if (!started) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Server was not started");
        }
    }
}

public class AudioServer extends AbstractServer{

     @Override
    public String request(String request) {
        return "Response from Audio server: " + request;
    }

}

public class VideoServer extends AbstractServer {

    @Override
    public String request(String request) {
        return "Response from Video server: " + request;
    }
}

@Module
public class ServerModule {

    public ServerModule() {
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("audio")
    @Singleton
    AudioServer provideAudioServer() {
        return new AudioServer();
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("video")
    @Singleton
    VideoServer provideVideoServer() {
        return new VideoServer();
    }
}
```

Please not ServerComponent.java is not compiling

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {ServerModule.class})
public interface ServerComponent {

    @Named("audio")
    Server provideAudioServer();

    @Named("video")
    Server provideVideoServer();

    void inject(TestInject inject);
}

    public class TestInject {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestInject.class.getSimpleName());

    @Inject
    @Named("audio")
    Server audioServer;

    @Inject
    @Named("video")
    Server videoServer;

    public TestInject() {
        ServerComponent component = DaggerServerComponent.builder()
                .build();
        component.inject(this);
    }

    public void testAudioServer() {
        String serverResponse = null;
        if (audioServer != null) {
            serverResponse = audioServer.request("game.mp3");
            logger.warning(serverResponse);
        } else {
            serverResponse = "audio server Failure";
            logger.info(serverResponse);
        }
    }

    public void testVideoServer() {
        String serverResponse = null;
        if (videoServer != null) {
            serverResponse = videoServer.request("movie.mp4");
            logger.warning(serverResponse);
        } else {
            serverResponse = "Video server Failure";
            logger.info(serverResponse);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestInject inject = new TestInject();
        inject.testAudioServer();
        inject.testVideoServer();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem seems to be related to the fact that you expect in the class `TestInject` a `Server` named `audio` while your provider returns `AudioServer` so dagger cannot satisfy your dependency.

Indeed don't forget that the annotation `@Named` is used to distinguish 2 objects **of the same type**, in other words you can annotate with `@Named("audio")` different providers as long as they don't return the same type. The object produced will then be identified by its type and its name.

**So for example here is one way to fix you problem:**

*The class `TestInject`:*

```
public class TestInject {
    ...

    public TestInject() {
        // Needed to inject your dependencies
        ServerComponent component = DaggerServerComponent.builder()
            .build();
        component.inject(this);
    }
    ...
}
```

*The class `ServerComponent`*

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = ServerModule.class)
public interface ServerComponent {
    void inject(TestInject inject);
}
```

*The class `ServerModule`*

```
@Module
public class ServerModule {

    @Provides
    @Named("audio")
    @Singleton
    public Server provideAudioServer() {
        return new AudioServer();
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("video")
    @Singleton
    public Server provideVideoServer() {
        return new VideoServer();
    }
}
```

---

Even with your question update, your module should be what I propose abose otherwise it won't compile for the same reason described previously.

Comment: how would my COmponent class would look, m not clear Module i made mistake should have been Super interface as you answered, can u please tell how would component class would look like.

Comment: if i dont added @Named annotation to Server component it wont compiler, component is responsible for providing Objects.